How to add a new row to an existing MS Word table using QT5?
In general I am trying to transfer data from QTableView to a prepared .docx file, where I will use a placeholder to replace the data I need.
At the moment I stopped at adding a new row to an existing table in an MS Word document, but I can't understand the syntax (it keeps saying "No such property in" with different functions).
The only thing that works correctly is getting the amount of tables in the document.
QAxObject *wApp = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
auto docs = wApp->querySubObject("Documents");
auto doc  = docs->querySubObject("Open(QString)","C:\\pathToFile\\qwe.docx");
if (doc == nullptr) {
    doc->dynamicCall("Close()");
    wApp->dynamicCall("Quit()");
    QMessageBox::information(this, "File opening", "File not found");
    return;
}

auto active  = wApp->querySubObject("ActiveDocument()");
auto tables  = active->querySubObject("Tables");

qDebug() << tables->dynamicCall("Count()");

// doc->dynamicCall("Save()");
doc->dynamicCall("Close()");
wApp->dynamicCall("Quit()");
delete wApp;

I also tried to get the amount of rows in the table but it outputs 0.
auto table = tables->querySubObject("Select(int)", 1);
qDebug() << table->dynamicCall("Rows");

Examples of errors:
QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: Table: No such property in {000209ff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} [Microsoft Word Application]
    Candidates are:
        TaskPanes
        Tasks
        Templates
        Top

QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: Type(QString): No such property in  [unknown]
    Candidates are:
        TableDirection
        Tables
        Title
        TopPadding


Short answer: the COM interface is defined by Word so it is used the same way in VBA and C++. Judging from tables->querySubObject("Select(int)", 1), the issue seems to be that you assumed tables was a Table. It is not: tables is a Tables collection. Better than fixing this code though: dumcpp will do the heavy lifting for you and create a header file with all the methods you need to write natural C++. More info here

@Atmo Okay. Tables is Tables. I managed to programmatically add a letter to the last column of the last row of the table. So  tables->querySubObject("Select(int)", 1) will be the index of the table I need to add a row to, right?
Also I didn't understand about dumpcpp, sorry

I see you have just answered your own question... And indeed, Tables (collection) does not have a method called Select unlike, funnily enough, Table (object). Regarding dumpcpp you need to read the help page + the answer (+ the link in the answer) I linked. It can greatly simplify the C++ (e.g. wApp->querySubObject("ActiveDocument()"); becomes wApp->ActiveDocument();). If you are not afraid to compile a huge file (>125MB, the MSOffice applications are huge...), it can be a great help.

I looked at dumpcpp back in the first time, but didn't look into it too much since I needed to solve the main problem. But now I think I get it, but I'm not sure if it's worth it. Anyway, thanks for your help

I tried to select the wrong member of the Tables class, which led to strange results (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tables.item), but after a detailed review of all MS Word functions (open MS Word, press Alt+F11 and then F2) I realized that must select a table by index using Item(Index As Long) As Table which will return the Table class.
The Table class has a Rows member in its properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.rows) with the help of which I just added a row to the table.
There is my solution
QAxObject *wApp = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
auto docs = wApp->querySubObject("Documents");
auto doc  = docs->querySubObject("Open(QString)", "C:\\pathToFile\\qwe.docx");
if (doc == nullptr) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "File opening", "File not found");
    wApp->dynamicCall("Quit()");
    delete wApp;
    return;
}

auto active = wApp->querySubObject("ActiveDocument()");
auto tables = active->querySubObject("Tables");
auto table  = tables->querySubObject("Item(int)", 1); // First table in the document

auto rows = table->querySubObject("Rows");
rows->dynamicCall("Add()");

doc->dynamicCall("Save()");
doc->dynamicCall("Close()");
wApp->dynamicCall("Quit()");
delete wApp;

Upd: Actually, to select the table you can just use auto table = doc->querySubObject("Tables(2)")
Like this
auto table = doc->querySubObject("Tables(2)"); // Row will be added to the second table
auto rows = table->querySubObject("Rows");
rows->dynamicCall("Add()");


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
